# theme language translation

Tags: magento2, theme, localisation, language

I have installed a new theme, I created the i18n directory with the csv file.
I entered this command to create the dictionary:

```
 php magento2/bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output="magento2/app/design/frontend/OrangeCo/orange/i18n/en_US.csv" magento2/app/design/frontend/OrangeCo/orange
```

To take effect I entered:

```
 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

The problem is that some link or button name are not translated.

Comment: did you run `php bin/magento i18n:pack magento2/app/design/frontend/OrangeCo/orange/i18n/en_US.csv -d en_US ` ?

Comment: No,I don't need a language pack.

Answer (score 0):

Please your link and button name write in this way

```
<?php echo __('your link and button name'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<?php / @escapeNotVerified / echo __('your link and button name') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you adding those button and link in phtml file then you can use it as

```
<?= __("Your desired text"); ?>
```

If you are adding this text from js file then use mage/translate.js for translation.

```
require([
'jquery', 
'mage/translate'
], function($){ 
 $(window).load(function() {
    alert($.mage.__('Your desired text'));
});
});
```

As in above example it is using $.mage.__("Your desired text"), you can also pass your text in the same way.

Hope this will help you.